# Meteor - Simple react router throwing errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, react-router

I have basically copied code straight from the documentation, and it is throwing a peculiar error.

```
 Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `history` is marked as required in
 `Router`, but its value is `undefined`.
     in Router
```

Here is my code:

> client/main.jsx

```
import React from "react"
import { render } from "react-dom"
import { Meteor } from "meteor/meteor"

import { renderRoutes } from "../imports/ui/Routes.jsx"

Meteor.startup(() => {
    render(renderRoutes(), document.getElementById('react-root'))
})
```

> imports/ui/Routes.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from "react-dom"
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, browserHistory } from 'react-router'

// route components
import App from "./App.jsx"

export const renderRoutes = () => (
   <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App} />
   </Router>
)
```

> imports/ui/App.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

import TopBar from "./components/TopBar.jsx"
import LeftMenuContainer from "./components/LeftMenuContainer.jsx"
import LivePurchases from "./components/LivePurchases.jsx"

// App component - represents the whole app
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <div className="flexWrapperGlobal">
                <TopBar/>
                <div className="contentContainer">
                    <LeftMenuContainer/>
                    <div className="bodyContainer">
                        <LivePurchases/>
                        <div className="siteContentContainer">
                            {this.props.children || "test"}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
  }
}
```

It appears that it should not be giving this error, as I am setting the prop at `history={browserHistory}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Switch over to the example from the [React Docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Router),

> imports/ui/Routes.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from "react-dom"
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router'
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'

// route components
import App from "./App.jsx"

const history = createBrowserHistory()
export const renderRoutes = () => (
   <Router history={history}>
    <Route path="/" component={App} />
   </Router>
)
```